# Strip out non-standard characters from a defind string output in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to strip out non standard characters from a defined string output in SQL, there will be quite a few so i would like to use case rather than replace however I cant get it to work.  Any suggestions?

```
select distinct(    CASE (SORT_CODE 
            + cast(replicate('0',8-len(ACCOUNT_NUMBER))
            + ACCOUNT_NUMBER as char(8)) 
            + '0' 
            + '17' --to be replaced by a check for a specific type
            + cast (replicate('0',11-len(replace(CURRENT_CHARGE_INCL,'.',''))) + replace(CURRENT_CHARGE_INCL,'.','') as char(11)) 
            + cast(left(LAST_NAME, 10) + replicate(' ',18) as char(18)) + upper(cast(TRADING_NAME + replicate(' ',18) as char( 18))) )

             WHEN '.' THEN ' '
             WHEN '&' THEN ' '
             WHEN ',' THEN ' '
             else DD_line
            END)
            as DD_LINE
```

Comment: Why does ACCOUNT_NUMBER have something other than a number? Should it not be named ACCOUNT_NUMBER_ID or something?

Comment: You must have had an warning when you tagged this with [tag:sql]. Why didn't you follow the advice and added the tag which RDBMS or SQL Flavor you're using? It looks like Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: What isn't working? What does your input look like and what is your expected and current output? Can you maybe provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Thanks for the info, the error i get for this configeration is "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Invalid column name 'DD_line'." I am trying to call the output DD_Line which is a single text string for each output line. erm sorry a bit of a newbee with SQL, Flavour?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 12.0.4459.0

Comment: Hm... might be mistaken, but I guess this query will not work for several reasons: First of all, you concat a whole lot of chars together with sort_code and compare (in your CASE) the result against a single char!?
Additionally, you put DD_line in your ELSE - so this requires a DD_line column to actually exist in your source. If this column isn't featured, you will recieve the "invalid column" error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your statement does not read as you think it does.
Your statement is essentially read like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN @string = '.' THEN ' '
                     WHEN @string = '&' THEN ' '
```

Instead, run `CASE` statements on the potentially offending columns/variables where you notice the code. If you have `CREATE` rights, use a `UDF` that processes this for each part or write it out properly. Your code will be much easier to read.

Unfortunately, you did not provide where in the statement the offending characters are, so something like this example will have to suffice:

```
select distinct(  (SORT_CODE 
            + cast(replicate('0',8-len( 
                                        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ACCOUNT_NUMBER) <> 0 THEN REPLACE(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '.', ' ')
                                             WHEN CHARINDEX('&', ACCOUNT_NUMBER) <> 0 THEN REPLACE(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '.', ' ')
                                             WHEN CHARINDEX(',', ACCOUNT_NUMBER) <> 0 THEN REPLACE(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '.', ' ') END
                                     )) )
            + CAST( CASE    WHEN CHARINDEX('.', ACCOUNT_NUMBER) <> 0 THEN REPLACE(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '.', ' ')
                            WHEN CHARINDEX('&', ACCOUNT_NUMBER) <> 0 THEN REPLACE(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, '&', ' ')
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(',', ACCOUNT_NUMBER) <> 0 THEN REPLACE(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ',', ' ') 
                            ELSE DD_LINE END as char(8)) 
                        ) 
                )
```

*Copy and paste did me in. xD*

Comment: Except you will put the corresponding char in the REPLACE as well (instead of '.' every time). ;-)

Comment: @Rene ha ha! #copypasteOP I adjusted the example. xD

Comment: many thanks for the frendly help provided on my first posted question. I will try the solution.

Answer (score 0):

found a great way to remove all non Alpha and no spaces, may be useful to some one else. create the function below then use it thus: dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters( TRADING_NAME  )

IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION RemoveNonAlphaCharacters;

```
go
```

Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

```
Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z ]%'
While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
    Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

Return @Temp
```

End

go

credit, G Mastros